# How can I split a string into two based on a character inbetween using REGEXP_EXTRACT?

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I need to split a string into two based on a character and I need to do this without using [`SPLIT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#split) command.

What I have:

| string |
| --- |
| fruit=orange |
| fruit=apple |
| vegetable=onion |

What I need:

| splitstring1 | splitstring2 |
| --- | --- |
| fruit | orange |
| fruit | apple |
| vegetable | onion |

How can I solve this with [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the below query for your requirement:

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(string, r'^[a-zA-Z]+') AS splitstring1,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(string, r'[a-zA-Z]+$') AS splitstring2
FROM
  `project.dataset.table`;
```

Result:

[image]

EDIT: Based on your new requirement:

- Sample Input: `fruit=apples and oranges`
- Expected Output: `"fruit" in one column and "apples and oranges" in another column`

Consider the below query:

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(string, r'^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+') AS splitstring1,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(string, r'[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$') AS splitstring2
FROM
  `project.dataset.table`;
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hey @Vishal K. Thanks for answering. This solves for alphabets, we can add for numbers too. But what if there are spaces in between ?

Comment: Hello @ThivagarMoorthy. Do you want to ignore or split at spaces? Share some sample input and expected output.

Comment: Hi @Vishak, Sure.
Sample Input:
fruit=apples and oranges 
Expected Output:
"fruit" in one column and "apples and oranges" in another column

Comment: Hi @ThivagarMoorthy. I have updated my answer based on your new requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select 
  arr[offset(0)] as splitstring1,
  arr[safe_offset(1)] as splitstring2
from  your_table,
unnest([struct(regexp_extract_all(string, r'[^=]+') as arr)])
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]